# Azure Stream Analytics job triggers False Positives missing assets on job start

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

On starting my on Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job I get several False Positives (FP) and I want to know what causes this.

I am trying to implement asset tracking in ASA as disccussed in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208844/asset-tracking-with-azure-stream-analytics). My specific use case is that I want to trigger events when an asset has not send a signal in the last 70 minutes. This works fine when the ASA job is running but triggers false positives on starting the job.

For example when starting the ASA-job at 2017-11-07T09:30:00Z. The ASA-job gives an entry with MostRecentSignalInWindow: 1510042968 (=2017-11-07T08:22:48Z) for name 'A'. while I am sure that there is another event for name 'A' with time: '2017-11-07T08:52:49Z' and one at '2017-11-07T09:22:49Z in the eventhub.

Some events arrive late due to the event ordering policy:

- Late: 5 seconds
- Out-of-order: 5 seconds
- Action: adjust

I use the below query:

```
WITH
Missing AS (
SELECT
    PreviousSignal.name,
    PreviousSignal.time,
FROM
    [signal-eventhub] PreviousSignal
TIMESTAMP BY
    time
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [signal-eventhub] CurrentSignal 
TIMESTAMP BY
    time
ON
    PreviousSignal.name= CurrentSignal.certname
AND
    DATEDIFF(second, PreviousSignal, CurrentSignal) BETWEEN 1 AND 4200
WHERE CurrentSignal.name IS NULL
),

EventsInWindow AS (
SELECT
    name,
    max(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01 00:00:00Z', time)) MostRecentSignalInWindow
FROM
    Missing
GROUP BY
    name,
    TumblingWindow(minute, 1)
)
```

Comment: Hi. It is possible that some if the timestamps may be adjusted due to time policies. Can you let me know if you see any dropped/adjusted events in the metrics section of the portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this, this was a confirmed bug in Azure Stream Analytics and has now been resolved.